# Android Development Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is how I would like my layout:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU5sZ.png

I want 2 to be 90% of 1's height. 3 should be 10% of 1's height.

I've tried having 1 be a LinearLayout, FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, but I can't get it to work. I'm thinking I'm just missing something simple.

Edit (Adding implementation):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_black_opaque">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you considered using WebView?

Comment: I have not, I'm new to this. I'll look into that and post back.

Edit: I'm not seeing how this would solve my problem.

Comment: show your implementation

Comment: @Virus, is the image not visible?

Comment: what i'm saying is you have asked a question, i asked to show your implementation if you have error we are here to solve, we are not here to write a code for you

Comment: Okay I can show my implementation of the code that doesn't work.

Comment: sorry sir, but all i am asking is if you have any error or mistake in the code please put that

Comment: @Virus, Okay I've added my code. Took me a minute to figure it out. See how I had to hard code the marginTop at -30dp. That doesn't quite work on all phone sizes. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cost"
        android:layout_height="60sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_content">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in java code get the device resolution height

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int deviceHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

and set your LayoutParams for your view2 and view3 programmatically.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsView3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0.9 * deviceHeight );
paramsView3 .addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
view3.setLayoutParams(paramsView3 );

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsView2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.2 * deviceHeight );
view2.setLayoutParams(paramsView2);
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't allow them to overlap. I would like them to overlap like the image shows.

Comment: How you want it? I mean do you want view3 to overlap exact half?

Comment: I would like view3 to overlap view2 by half of view3's height.

Comment: Yes, this could work. I could see grabbing the height of the device and calculating the offset for view3. Hmm. I might have to play around with this idea before I'd know if it's the best solution. Thanks a lot @Kunu